# Error al llamnar a una Activity desde un fragment

Tags: android

Me sale un error al llamar a una activity desde un fragment (proviene de un Navigation Drawer Activity y tiene un reciclerview adaptado, aunque esto no tenga nada que ver).

El codigo es

```
      @Override
        public void onImagenDetalleClick(TablaDivisiones tablaDivisiones, String iddivivision) {
            // Pasar a equipos

            gmiddivision = iddivivision;
            gmdivision = tablaDivisiones.getNombredivision();
            Intent intentdiv = new Intent(getActivity(), MainEquipos.class);
            intentdiv.putExtra("pasenombrediv", gmdivision);
            intentdiv.putExtra("paseiddiv", gmiddivision);
            startActivity( intentdiv );



        }
```

y el erro me sale en, vamos que crachea la App

```
startActivity( intentdiv );


      at com.valhondo.delgado.f7vmadmin.Divisiones.FragmentDivisiones$1.onImagenDetalleClick(FragmentDivisiones.java:208)
    at com.valhondo.delgado.f7vmadmin.Divisiones.DivisionAdapter$3.onClick(DivisionAdapter.java:75)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6605)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6582)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22339 SIG: 9

Comment: Es recomendable agregar el error desplegado en el LogCat desde donde dice "Caused by", saludos

Comment: OK era eso.
Muchas gracias. Un saludo

Comment: Recuerda también marcar las preguntas que solucionen el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos. @FernandoDelgadoFernandez

Answer (score 0):

Asegura registrar la Activity `MainEquipos` a la cual realizarías el Intent, esto dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <activity android:name="MainEquipos"/>
```